# Configuring velocity in Animated.decay to dismiss view with flick gesture

Tags: react-native, animation

I'm trying implement a 'drag down to dismiss' gesture in my React Native app using Animated.decay to take the velocity from the `onPanResponderRelease` handler and feed that into the decay.

The only this is I don't really understand what my velocity and deceleration should be. I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of these values. Any values I put in (whether it's the `gesturestate.vy` from `onPanResponderRelease` or static values I enter manually) don't result in a fluid animation and the view just disappears immediately.

I'm playing with values like

```
Animated.decay(this.props.dismissVal, {
  velocity: 0.03,
  deceleration: 0.997
});
```

And `dismissVal` is used like

```
top: this.props.dismissVal.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, _containerLayout.height]
})
```

I've looked a lot over the [react-native-animated-tinder](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-animated-demo-tinder) example, with no luck. I'm having trouble understanding what the value of velocity (and deceleration) should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget start decay. `Animated.decay({...}).start();`

And the second mistake could be trying of change `this.props`. Everything what you pass to component as a prop, can be change only in parent component. In your child component it is final variable.

```
//constructor
this.state = { animatedValue: new Animated.Value() }
....
....
Animated.decay(this.state.animatedValue, {...}).start();
```